# How to replace pound sign £ in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections, scalaz

In sales column i have values with pound sign £1200. It is not readable by Data frame in scala, please help me for the same. i want column value in double, 1200. I am using below method but its not working.

```
def getRemovedDollarValue = udf(
  (actualSales: String) => {
    val actualSalesDouble = actualSales
      .replace(",", "")
      .replace("$", "")
      .replace("\\u00A3","")
      .replace("\\U00A3","")
      .replaceAll("\\s", "_").trim().toDouble

    java.lang.Double.parseDouble(actualSalesDouble.toString)
  }
)
```

Comment: 'actualSalesDouble' does it still store £1200 ?

Comment: Can you also try this instead? replace(/\u00A3/g, '')

Comment: Why just simple:       ```.replace("£", "")``` as you do for ```$```

Answer (score 1):

You need write:  `.replace("\u00A3","")` instead of  escaping     `.replace("\\u00A3","")`.

But I prefer just: `.replace("£", "")` - it is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I think the proposed solutions and comments all work but don't address the confusion behind why your code isn't working.

From the Pattern docs:

> Thus the strings "\u2014" and "\\u2014", while not equal, compile into the same pattern, which matches the character with hexadecimal value 0x2014.

`replace` and `replaceAll` are both replacing all occurrences in a String, but only `replaceAll` is taking in a regular expression. You're passing in `"\\u00A3"` which will work as a pattern, but not a unicode literal due to the added backslash. As already suggested, either use replace with a unicode literal or the actual symbol, or change to `replaceAll`.